# get current running thread executor service clojure

Tags: concurrency, clojure, executorservice

I'm using ExecutorService to execute my asks in parallel using clojure. The code is as below:

```
(let [pool (Executors/newFixedThreadPool 6)
      tasks #(doseq [{:keys [msisdn repay_time loan_request_id transaction_amount repayment_type]} (fetch-data)]
                (util/send-notification msisdn loan_request_id (str repay_time) repayment_type transaction_amount)
                )
      task-res (.submit pool tasks)]
  (.get task-res))
```

I need a way of logging the current working thread. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 3):

To get the current running thread use `currentThread` method in java's [`Thread` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), like this:

```
(.getName (Thread/currentThread))
```

Comment: @G.Joe this looks like the "whole code" to me.
If you want to log it use `(println (.getName (Thread/currentThread)))` or whatever logging mechanism you want to use.